# kendo ui grid cell empty message

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

If data for a cell is missing in the grid dataSource, the output is undefined/null, depending on the cell type String/Number.
I haven't found a way to specify a default message for an empty cell yet.

field: "title",

title: "Title",

template: "#: UnitPrice #",

***noDataMessage: "noData...",***

width: "auto",

Is there a way to store a standard message for an empty cell, like noDataMessage?

My small Sample Code: https://dojo.telerik.com/AKInuYEG/2

The data set Ikura has no UnitPrice, hence the output of the empty cell with null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i know, there is no configuration for cell/column like "NoDataMessage", so you should check your property for null in template:

```
template: "<div class=\'priceTempl\'>#: UnitPrice != null ?  UnitPrice : 'No data'#</div>"
```